# Base64 String decoding issue in Java 7

Tags: java, c#, base64, decode, apache-commons

I got a Base64 encoded string, which I want to decode on Java 7 in my engine.
The String is this:

```
String msg = "TwBuACAAMAAzACAATQBhAHIAIAAxADQALAAgAGEAdAAgADEAOQAyADkAaAByAHMALAAg
    AFMAeQByAGkAYQBuACAAagBlAHQAcwAgAGYAaQByAGUAZAAgADEAOAAgAHIAbwBjAGsAZQB0AHMAIA
    BhAHQAIABBAHIAcwBhAGwAJwBzACAAVwBhAGQAaQAgAEsAaABhAGkAcgAgAGEAbgBkACAAdABoAGUA
    IAByAG8AYQBkACAAYgBlAHQAdwBlAGUAbgAgAFMAbABlAGUAdABhACAAYQBuAGQAIABuAG8AcgB0AG
    gAZQByAG4AIAB0AG8AdwBuACAAbwBmACAAQQByAHMAYQBsAC0AQgBhAGEAbABiAGUAawAgAGEAcgBl
    AGEALgA=";
```

It comes from a web service written in C#.

If I paste it in any **Base64 decoder** on the web it works fine. If I use **apache commons decoder** it will give me weird output, where every letter is followed by a black diamond with questionmark (see sreenshot)[image: Screenshot of Output]:

I Have tried to set encodings before decoding and when converting to a String, but with no success.
Here is the code:

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");       
String enc =
System.getProperty("file.encoding","UTF-8");
System.out.println(enc);        
String msg = "TwBuACAAMAAzACAATQBhAHIAIAAxADQALAAgAGEAdAAgADEAOQAyADkAaAByAHMALAAg
    AFMAeQByAGkAYQBuACAAagBlAHQAcwAgAGYAaQByAGUAZAAgADEAOAAgAHIAbwBjAGsAZQB0AHMAIA
    BhAHQAIABBAHIAcwBhAGwAJwBzACAAVwBhAGQAaQAgAEsAaABhAGkAcgAgAGEAbgBkACAAdABoAGUA
    IAByAG8AYQBkACAAYgBlAHQAdwBlAGUAbgAgAFMAbABlAGUAdABhACAAYQBuAGQAIABuAG8AcgB0A
    GgAZQByAG4AIAB0AG8AdwBuACAAbwBmACAAQQByAHMAYQBsAC0AQgBhAGEAbABiAGUAawAgAGEAcgB
    lAGEALgA=";

byte[] res = Base64.decodeBase64(msg);      
System.out.println(new String(res, "UTF-8"));
```

Any ideas?

Kind Regards,
Kartopete

Comment: First question: What character encoding is the underlying data in? If it's (for instance) UTF-16, then the result isn't too surprising depending on how you're viewing it...

Comment: If I put your base64 string into [this online base64 decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) I also get black diamonds in between of the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is in **UTF-16LE** encoding, according to Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html): *Sixteen-bit Unicode (or UCS) Transformation Format, little-endian byte order*. More information about UTF-16 variants can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

After converting your base64 string to bytes, do as follows:

```
byte[] bytes; // base64 decoded bytes
String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-16LE");
```

The value of the string is:

> On 03 Mar 14, at 1929hrs, Syrian jets fired 18 rockets at Arsal's Wadi
>   Khair and the road between Sleeta and northern town of Arsal-Baalbek
>   area.

Comment: Cool, I tried all kind of combination, without success. This one indeed did the trick! Thx Robby. Hero

Answer (score 0):

my output in eclipse,

```
String msg = "TwBuACAAMAAzACAATQBhAHIAIAAxADQALAAgAGEAdAAgADEAOQAyADkAaAByAHMALAAgAFMAeQByAGkAYQBuACAAagBlAHQAcwAgAGYAaQByAGUAZAAgADEAOAAgAHIAbwBjAGsAZQB0AHMAIABhAHQAIABBAHIAcwBhAGwAJwBzACAAVwBhAGQAaQAgAEsAaABhAGkAcgAgAGEAbgBkACAAdABoAGUAIAByAG8AYQBkACAAYgBlAHQAdwBlAGUAbgAgAFMAbABlAGUAdABhACAAYQBuAGQAIABuAG8AcgB0AGgAZQByAG4AIAB0AG8AdwBuACAAbwBmACAAQQByAHMAYQBsAC0AQgBhAGEAbABiAGUAawAgAGEAcgBlAGEALgA=";
byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64(msg);
System.out.println(new String(b));
```

Output

*On 03 Mar 14, at 1929hrs, Syrian jets fired 18 rockets at Arsal's Wadi Khair and the road between Sleeta and northern town of Arsal-Baalbek area.*

Comment: Because you're on Windows, and your platform's default encoding is probably set to little-endian UTF-16.